# How can I control exceptions on Spring Boot startup?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Spring Boot application tries to load some certificate files on startup. I want to be able to show a sensible message when that file cannot be loaded instead of a huge stack trace.

The certificate file is being loaded in a @PostConstruct method inside a @Component class. If it throws a FileNotFoundException I catch it and throw a specific exception that I created. I need to throw an exception in any case because I don't want the application to load if that file is not read.

I tried this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FileLoadTestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(FileLoadTestApplication .class, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Application ending due to an error.");
            if (e.getClass().equals(ConfigException.class)) {
                if (e.getCause().getClass().equals(FileNotFoundException.class)) {
                    LOGGER.error("Unable to read file: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
                } else {
                    LOGGER.error("Initial configuration failed.", e.getCause());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the exception is not thrown inside inside the run method.

How can I control some exceptions on startup so that I show an informative message before closing?

Answer (score 4):

You can catch the `BeanCreationException` and unwrap it to get the original cause. You can use the following code fragment

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SpringApplication.run(FileLoadTestApplication.class, args);
    } catch (BeanCreationException ex) {
        Throwable realCause = unwrap(ex);
        // Perform action based on real cause
    }
}

public static Throwable unwrap(Throwable ex) {
    if (ex != null && BeanCreationException.class.isAssignableFrom(ex.getClass())) {
        return unwrap(ex.getCause());
    } else {
        return ex;
    }
}
```

When the `@PostConstruct` annotated method throws an exception, Spring wraps it inside the `BeanCreationException` and throws back.

Comment: Thank you. This indeed allows me to know what exception was thrown and do something about it. Unfortunately it does that AFTER showing the whole stack trace. Can't this be prevented?